# hwioath symfony bundle /login/check-* handler missed

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

Ok, I'm writing symfony2 + hwioauth + fosuser project. Trying to understand work of hwi bundle. 
So, when user has authorized to his social account he redirecting to /connect action to my app. So after that by routing it calls HWI connect controller and redirectToServiceAction that is redirects user to /login/check-{service_name} path (i.e. /login/check-facebook).
The question is that concrete service or controller (I'm looking for a function) handles this route?